# Need some help with linking to model views in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, models

I'm working on a Dungeons and Dragons character database application. I've got a Character model and several models that belong to Character with a has_one association, such as HitPoints, ArmorClass and so on. These are all built, edited and displayed from the Character view. However, I want to create new pages with more information that belongs to the Character model. I want a link at the top of the view that takes the user to an Equipment page, with separate models displayed on that page, such as Weapons, Armor, Gear and so forth.

This is where I need some guidance. Would the Equipment page be a new model that belongs_to Character and I just load models for Weapon, Armor, Gear and so forth into the Equipment view?

If so, would these models have a belongs_to relationship with the Character model, the Equipment model or both?

Finally, if I build it this way: Character has_one Equipment and Equipment has_many Weapons, would the Weapons model also have a belongs_to relationship with the Character model?

Thanks in advance, I hope what I'm trying to do is clear. I'm still having trouble talking about what I want to accomplish with Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're misunderstanding some of the concepts around models. For example, `HitPoints` and `ArmorClass` should not be models that have a `has_one` association with your `Character`. They are just attributes of `Character`. So your model should look something like this instead:

```
class Character
  attr_accessor :name, :hit_points, :armor_class

  def initialize(name, hitpoints=10, armor_class=0)
    @name = name
    @hitpoints = hitpoints
    @armor_class = armor_class
  end
  # some other stuff, etc
end
```

Then you can access them like so:

```
fighter = Character.new("Conan", 100, 12)
puts "I am #{fighter.name} and I have #{fighter.hit_points} hitpoints."
puts fighter.armor_class  # outputs 12
```

Also, I'd say `Equipment` model is the wrong concept. What you need is an `Item` model. All of the things you mentioned (weapons, armor, gear) are all just items. And it makes a lot more sense that a "Character" `has_many` "Items". Also that "Item" `has_many` "Characters" since you'll presumably have multiple characters with multiple items...so it COULD be a many to many relationship to keep it simple. Then your "Item" model could have an "ItemType" field which tells you if it's a weapon, armor, potion, etc.

So your `Item` model could look like this

```
class Item
  attr_accessor :name, :type

  def initialize(name, type)
    @name = name
    @type = type
  end
end
```

Another option, which is closer to what you're talking about is to add an `ItemSet` model. We'd put this model between `Character` and `Items`. Doing it this way would let you say

- "Character" `has_one` "ItemSet"
- "ItemSet" `has_many` "Items"
- Character" has many "Items" through "ItemSet"

So basically, this is showing that in your "world" you have many characters and items. But each character has a unique set of those items.

This is the way I'd do it.

In the code above you need to add the `has_many`, `has_one`, etc attributes to the models. I left it out so you could see the models themselves a little easier and so you could figure out how you want to do it yourself.

Comment: I'd originally made HitPoints and ArmorClass as models because each of them had several components or data to display (HitPoints has total and current HP, ArmorClass has armor, shield, bonuses, etc) and I figured it would be easier to keep them organized and to style them later. Is there any real draw back to doing it this way versus making them as attributes? I like your suggestion for the Item and ItemSet models, that definitely gives me some food for thought.

Comment: I think it would still be simpler to have Character.total_hit_points and Character.current_hit_points rather than a relationship. Hit points seem too related to character to be its own model. ArmorClass may need a different model depending on what properties it may have.

Comment: Well, I think you might be modeling it wrong conceptually. Hitpoints could be total_hitpoints and current_hitpoints attributes. And ArmorClass is just a number isn't it? It's calculated, but it's still just a number. I don't see these two things as models. If we use your current model logic then "Name" could be an object as well. And a "Character" has_one "Name". Doesn't make sense to me and adds a layer of complexity without adding much benefit. A "Character" has a "name" attribute makes much more sense.

Comment: My original thinking was to make things that change often as associated models. Therefore, hit points, armor class, etc, were built as associated models, both to keep them separate and easy to edit. I made name, class, race, sex, etc into attributes because these things are static and won't change. I agree I'm adding a bit of needless complexity here, though.